# Plot multiple data on each plot in series of subplots using for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, axis, subplot

I am trying to plot wind speed and wind direction for multiple levels on one large series of subplots using `plt.subplots()`.

I have:

```
fig, axes=plt.subplots(n=levels,figsize=(20,30),sharex=True)
for i in range(levels):
     axes[i].plot(time,wind_speed[:,i])
```

How can I add the second y-axis on each subplot so I can plot wind speed and wind direction on the same plot for each level? I don't understand how do add a second axis second axes cannot be enumerated this way.

Each plot will have the same x-axis, but wind speed on a line plot (left y-axis) and wind direction as dots (right y-axis). `twinx` would work but Python does not like `twinx` when using iteration in a for loop.

I tried `axes[0][i]=axes[i].twinx`
I also tried to do a another nested `for loop` with `for j...` to do `axes[j]=axes[i].twinx`. None of this worked.

Comment: Please unlock my question. The one you called a "duplicate" is nothing like I am asking. It has only thing plotted on each plot and I am asking about 2 datasets per plot. Please unlock.

Comment: Is your question about how to [`twinx`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html)?

Comment: Yes. I have tried twinx on this in several ways but cannot figure how to do it with the for loop I have.

Comment: Please can you share a small example and describe the expected output?

Comment: "twinx would work but Python does not like twinx when using iteration in a for loop." What makes you say that? Can you post the corresponding code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no info and limited understanding of your problem but I guess this might do:

the input argument: `sharex = True` allows you to keep the same axis **across** subplots.

My understanding is that within one plot you want a left and right y-axis:

```
fig, axes=plt.subplots(n=levels,figsize=(20,30),sharex=True)
for i in range(levels):
     axes[i].plot(time, wind_speed[:, i])
     ax2 = axes[i].twinx()
     ax2.plot(time, wind_direction[:, i])
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought all "axes" had to have a [i] iteration but I guess I was overthinking

Comment: no prob. you are welcome. Next time try to post a small example of your data, you'd have had an answer in a sec from one of the other users.